# how to rotate textblock dynamically in wpf using c#?

Tags: c#, wpf

I am trying like this but I am not getting the rotation. I am getting following error:

> Unable to cast object of type 'System.Windows.Media.TransformGroup' to
>   type 'System.Windows.Media.RotateTransform'.

```
TextBlock txt = new TextBlock();
txtb.Text="Sample";

var rotateAnimation = new DoubleAnimation(0, 270, TimeSpan.FromSeconds(5));

var rt = (RotateTransform)txt.RenderTransform;
rt.BeginAnimation(RotateTransform.AngleProperty, rotateAnimation);
```

Comment: "it was not getting" doesn't tell us what you observed. We don't even know where this code exists in your project. Please take some more time to ask your question thoroughly.

Answer (score 0):

if i understood you clearly what you want is to animate Textblock!

```
        TextBlock txt = new TextBlock();            
        txt.Text = "Sample";
        txt.HorizontalAlignment = HorizontalAlignment.Center;
        txt.VerticalAlignment = VerticalAlignment.Center;
        RotateTransform r1 = new RotateTransform();
        txt.RenderTransform = r1;
        MainGrid.Children.Add(txt);  //MainGrid is the name of your main layout

        var rotateAnimation = new DoubleAnimation(0, 270, TimeSpan.FromSeconds(5));
        rotateAnimation.RepeatBehavior = RepeatBehavior.Forever;
        var rt = (RotateTransform)txt.RenderTransform;
        rt.BeginAnimation(RotateTransform.AngleProperty, rotateAnimation);
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this one. You can use an animation on the RenderTransform:

```
var rotateAnimation = new DoubleAnimation(0, 270, TimeSpan.FromSeconds(5));
var rt = (RotateTransform) textblock2.RenderTransform;
rt.BeginAnimation(RotateTransform.AngleProperty, rotateAnimation);
```

In your Xaml, you can add the RotateTransform:

```
<TextBlock>
  <TextBlock.RenderTransform>
    <RotateTransform Angle="0"/>
  </TextBlock.RenderTransform>
</TextBlock>
```

Comment: it will be work fine at design time but i need dynamically at runtime